# Mirror traffic to tcpdump server and automatically save pcaps

Tags: linux, tcpdump, pcap

Looking to port mirror a network firewall interface, connect that interface to a Linux server, and have that Linux server constantly run a tcpdump and storing the output in files.

Specifically, my requirement is to have pcap files saved over and over again as the size of that file reaches a specific number.

For example:

Juniper firewall port 2 mirrors all traffic on port 1.  Port 2 connects to eth0 on the Linux server.  Linux server has a tcpdump process running constantly on eth0.  Linux server is configured to save the traffic to a file named "tcpdump.pcap", but when the pcap file exceeds a specific size, then it will then compress and rename to "tcpdump.pcap.0.gz".  As the second file exceeds a specific size, then it will be renamed to "tcpdump.pcap.1.gz", etc.

This will allow me to view network traffic within the past X amount of time (for now, I'm looking to have visibility in the past 72 hours).

The problem here is that I don't know how to accomplish the above.  Specifically, how do I get tcpdump to run continously, and automatically save pcaps, and automatically compress and re-name chronologically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down the problem in the following parts:

- **let `tcpdump` save the dump in pcap format**: you can use the `-w` option. As alway, [read the man page carefully](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html)
- **continuously run `tcpdump`**: you can use `screen` to run `tcpdump`, than detach/attach at your will; the process will continue to run until you stop it;
- **rotate the logfile**: [as per Mark Riddell suggestion] you can use the `-C` option to let `tcpdump` rotate the pcap file or, alternatively, you can configure and use `logrotate` to automatically rename/rotate the logfile when a specific size is reached

Comment: excellent, will look into this and thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Rather than using logrotate, you can use the in-built tcpdump rotation options (also found in the man page). For example, use the `-C 10` flag to automatically save to a new pcap file after the current one has exceeded 10MB. This can be combined with the `-W 5` option to limit the maximum number of saved captures (working as a ring buffer).

Comment: Very good to know, thank you ;) I'll update the answer with your suggestion.